# Saving all successful logins to MySQL database...Is it wise?

Tags: mysql, authentication

So I'm looking for some clearance, or advice as it were. I've set up my login system to save information about a user every time they sign in. I.e. IP Address, the ID of the user they've signed into, the timestamp, etc.

Now, my question is...is this wise? The reason I've done it is for future reference, if I ever needed to look into someone's account. This way I'll be able to see and pull back the information regarding every single time their user account has been accessed. It will allow me to see if someone has been accessing their account who shouldn't have been etc.

However, as the population of the database grows the table of all logins is going to become massive because a row is inserted every single time someone successfully signs into an account.

So, will this have any affect on my database further down the line, or is what I've done here perfectly fine?

Thank you for any advice you can give.

Comment: It's difficult to answer because you can come up with reasons pro and con. If you need it and if you plan to *query* your database for data in the future, the it's not unwise. If your system doesn't host a huge amount of data, then it's also not unwise. Usually, information about logs goes to dedicated machines. System administrators prefer using `syslog` which can be configured to store logs anywhere, and usually logging info goes there and it can be piped to other databases. Basically, **you** have to list reasons for and against and then come up with a conclusion.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately the answer is "it depends". The factors affecting the decision include but aren't limited to your server hardware and number of active users.

In general I don't see a problem with saving this login data to a database table. If you don't need historical data for logins after a certain amount of time you can delete old login data to manage the table size.

I would try it and monitor the table size and system performance over time. If it grows too fast then reevaluate its importance versus strategies to optimize it and keep the functionality. It all depends on your specific situation.

I wouldn't skip capturing data I think is important because it *might* cause problems. I would test and evaluate it over time, then use real metrics to guide my decision.

Comment: `use real metrics` is the key here.

Comment: Thank you, I'll take your advice on board